# Should outdoor rug be used on wood decks?

Tags: flooring, decking

I have wood deck.  It get's periodically treated.  The last treatment was 3-4 years ago.

Was wondering if it's alright to put an outdoor rug (8x10 ft.) on it?  Will be placing chair and outdoor gas heater on top of rug.
Located in central Iowa
Thanks,

Comment: What is it “periodically treated” with?

Answer (score 3):

When you put something like that on a wood deck, blocking the sun, that portion of the wood will not fade at the same rate as the rest. So when you eventually remove it, you will see a "shadow" of where it was. Also, if the outdoor rug holds moisture, it may accelerate any wood rot that might otherwise have been avoided or slowed down by periodic drying.